Trying to locate and click a button element, but Selenium Webdriver raises NoSuchElementException
Been trying out every selector and attribute I can possibly think of, so as to target and click a sign-up button on a website's homepage... all to no avail.
See the website: https://onepetro.org
Once the webdriver is started, all events are executed until it gets to the point when the button is to be clicked, then I get a NoSuchElementException.
Any suggestions or recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks
def user_auth(self, username:str, password:str):
        ''' Authenticate the user with the given username and password\n 
            Returns the captcha status, login status and username(if logged-in)'''
        if not self.at_homepage:
            self.go_to_homepage()
        self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown-toggle.signin').click()   # toggles the sign in dropdown

        WebDriverWait(self, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_LoginFormPopup")),
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pass_LoginFormPopup"))
        )
        username_field = self.find_element(By.ID, "user_LoginFormPopup")
        username_field.clear()
        username_field.send_keys(username + Keys.TAB)

        password_field = self.find_element(By.ID, "pass_LoginFormPopup")
        password_field.clear()
        password_field.send_keys(password)

        WebDriverWait(self, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')),     # Wait for the reCAPTCHA to load
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sign-in-dropdown > div > div > div.login-form__section-wrap > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(7) > button'))
        )
        self.solve_captcha()
        self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sign-in-dropdown > div > div > div.login-form__section-wrap > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(7) > button').click()    # Click the sign in button
        # self.execute_script("document.querySelector('.signin-button').click();")    # Click the sign in button

        try:
            # user_menu = self.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sign-in-dropdown"]/div')
            _ = self.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sign-in-dropdown"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')     # Check for presence of error message
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            self.logged_in = True; self.username = username
        else:
            self.logged_in = False
        return self.captcha_status, self.logged_in, self.username

Tried using a couple of selectors including XPATH, NAME, CLASS, ID and the CSS selector itself, but it all yielded the same NoSuchElementException. Am still confused as to why none worked.

I believe issue might be related to  switching into the iframe to solve the Captcha, but post that not switching to the default content,
since the sign up button is outside the iframe.
I ran a sanity flow to check it, its working fine for me.
iframe = d.find_element(By.XPATH,'//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')
d.switch_to.frame(iframe)
d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.recaptcha-checkbox-border').click()
d.switch_to.default_content()
time.sleep(50) #I am manually solving the captcha here. 
d.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="Sign In"]').click()
time.sleep(20) #To view the button click

